# Conditionally split comma separated values in PySpark list

Tags: python, list, csv, pyspark

I'm attempting to run a job in PySpark. My data is in an RDD created using the the PySpark spark context class (sc) as follows:

`directory_file = sc.textFile('directory.csv')`

*I do not think that Python's csv module can be used on data within an RDD.

This produces a list for every row within the csv. I know this is obnoxious, but here's a sample of one list (equating to a row from the original csv):

```
[u'14K685,El Puente Academy for Peace and Justice,Brooklyn,K778,718-387-1125,718-387-4229,9,12,,,"B24, B39, B44, B44-SBS, B46, B48, B57, B60, B62, Q54, Q59","G to Broadway ; J, M to Hewes St ; Z to Marcy Ave",250 Hooper Street,Brooklyn,NY,11211,www.elpuente.us,225,N/A,Consortium School,"We are a small, innovative learning community that promotes comprehensive academic excellence for all students while inspiring and nurturing leadership for peace and justice. Our state-of-the-art facility allows for a creative and intellectually challenging environment where every student thrives. Our project-based curriculum is designed to prepare students to be active citizens and independent thinkers who share a passion for transforming their communities and the world into a better place. Our trimester system allows students to complete most of their high school credits by the 11th grade, opening opportunities for exciting internships and college courses during the school day in their senior year.","Accelerated credit accumulation (up to 18 credits per year), iLearn, iZone 360, Year-long SAT (Scholastic Aptitude Test) preparatory course, Individualized college counseling, Early College Awareness & Preparatory Program (ECAPP). Visits to college campuses in NYC, Visits to colleges outside NYC in partnership with the El Puente Leadership Center, Internships, Community-based Projects, Portfolio Assessment, Integrated-Arts Projects, Before- and After-school Tutoring; Elective courses include: Drama, Dance (Men\'s and Women\'s Groups), Debate Team partnership with Tufts University, Guitar, Filmmaking, Architecture, Glee",Spanish,,,,"AM and PM Academic Support, B-Boy/B-Girl, Chorus, College and Vocational Counseling and Placement, College Prep, Community Development Project, Computers, Dance Level 1 and 2, Individual Drama; Education for Public Inquiry and International Citizenship (EPIIC), El Puente Leadership Center, Film, Fine Arts, Liberation, Media, Men\u2019s and Women\u2019s Groups, Movement Theater Level 1, Movement Theater Level 2, Music, Music Production, Pre-professional training in Dance, PSAT/SAT Prep, Spoken Word, Student Council, Teatro El Puente, Visual Art",,,,"Boys & Girls Basketball, Baseball, Softball, Volleyball",El Puente Williamsburg Leadership Center; The El Puente Bushwick Center; Leadership Center at Taylor-Wythe Houses; Beacon Leadership Center at MS50.,"Woodhull Medical Center, Governor Hospital","Hunter College (CUNY), Eugene Lang College The New School for Liberal Arts, Pratt College of Design, Tufts University, and Touro College.","El Puente Leadership Center, El Puente Bushwick Center, Beacon Leadership Center at MS50, Leadership Center at Taylor-Wythe Houses, Center for Puerto Rican Studies, Hip- Hop Theatre Festival, Urban Word, and Summer Search.",,,,,Our school requires assessment of an Academic Portfolio for graduation.,,9:00 AM,3:30 PM,This school will provide students with disabilities the supports and services indicated on their IEPs.,ESL,Not Functionally Accessible,1,Priority to Brooklyn students or residents,Then to New York City residents,,,,,,,,,"250 Hooper Street']
```

I want to split each list item using the comma as the delimiter except when the comma is between double quotes (e.g. ", , ,").

`parsed = directory_file.map(lambda x: x.split(','))` clearly doesn't address commas between double quotes. Is there a way to do this? I've seen this asked with specific reference to a csv, but since in this case the csv is first loaded into a Spark RDD, I'm pretty sure the `csv` module does not apply here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression. It works really fast with in PySpark:

```
import re
rdd=sc.textFile("factbook.csv")

# Get rid of those commas we do not need
cleanedRdd=rdd.map(lambda x:re.match( r'(.*".*)(,)(.*".*)', x, re.M|re.I).group(1)+" "re.match( r'(.*".*)(,)(.*".*)', x, re.M|re.I).group(3) if re.match( r'(.*".*)(,)(.*".*)', x, re.M|re.I) !=None else x)
```

So for each line similar to this:

```
col1,"col2,blabla",col3
```

This code matches a Regex pattern. If the pattern is found, it creates 3 groups:

- Group 1: col1,"col2
- Group 2: ,
- Group 3: blabla",col3

Finally we concatenate Group 1 and Group 2 and output will be:

```
col1,"col2 blabla",col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, this should work:

```
new_csv = [""]
inside_quotes = False
pos = 0
for letter in csv:
    if letter == ",":
        if inside_quotes:
            new_csv[pos] += letter
        else:
            new_csv.append("")
            pos += 1
    elif letter == '"':
        inside_quotes = not inside_quotes  # Switch inside_quotes to True if False or vice versa.
    else:
        new_csv[pos] += letter

new_csv = [x for x in new_csv if x != ''] # Remove all '' 's.
print(new_csv)
```

**Output**

```
['14K685', 'El Puente Academy for Peace and Justice', 'Brooklyn', 'K778', '718-387-1125', '718-387-4229', '9', '12', 'B24, B39, B44, B44-SBS, B46, B48, B57, B60, B62, Q54, Q59', 'G to Broadway ; J, M to Hewes St ; Z to Marcy Ave', '250 Hooper Street', 'Brooklyn', 'NY', '11211', 'www.elpuente.us', '225', 'N/A', 'Consortium School', 'We are a small, innovative learning community that promotes comprehensive academic excellence for all students while inspiring and nurturing leadership for peace and justice. Our state-of-the-art facility allows for a creative and intellectually challenging environment where every student thrives. Our project-based curriculum is designed to prepare students to be active citizens and independent thinkers who share a passion for transforming their communities and the world into a better place. Our trimester system allows students to complete most of their high school credits by the 11th grade, opening opportunities for exciting internships and college courses during the school day in their senior year.', "Accelerated credit accumulation (up to 18 credits per year), iLearn, iZone 360, Year-long SAT (Scholastic Aptitude Test) preparatory course, Individualized college counseling, Early College Awareness & Preparatory Program (ECAPP). Visits to college campuses in NYC, Visits to colleges outside NYC in partnership with the El Puente Leadership Center, Internships, Community-based Projects, Portfolio Assessment, Integrated-Arts Projects, Before- and After-school Tutoring; Elective courses include: Drama, Dance (Men's and Women's Groups), Debate Team partnership with Tufts University, Guitar, Filmmaking, Architecture, Glee", 'Spanish', 'AM and PM Academic Support, B-Boy/B-Girl, Chorus, College and Vocational Counseling and Placement, College Prep, Community Development Project, Computers, Dance Level 1 and 2, Individual Drama; Education for Public Inquiry and International Citizenship (EPIIC), El Puente Leadership Center, Film, Fine Arts, Liberation, Media, Men’s and Women’s Groups, Movement Theater Level 1, Movement Theater Level 2, Music, Music Production, Pre-professional training in Dance, PSAT/SAT Prep, Spoken Word, Student Council, Teatro El Puente, Visual Art', 'Boys & Girls Basketball, Baseball, Softball, Volleyball', 'El Puente Williamsburg Leadership Center; The El Puente Bushwick Center; Leadership Center at Taylor-Wythe Houses; Beacon Leadership Center at MS50.', 'Woodhull Medical Center, Governor Hospital', 'Hunter College (CUNY), Eugene Lang College The New School for Liberal Arts, Pratt College of Design, Tufts University, and Touro College.', 'El Puente Leadership Center, El Puente Bushwick Center, Beacon Leadership Center at MS50, Leadership Center at Taylor-Wythe Houses, Center for Puerto Rican Studies, Hip- Hop Theatre Festival, Urban Word, and Summer Search.', 'Our school requires assessment of an Academic Portfolio for graduation.', '9:00 AM', '3:30 PM', 'This school will provide students with disabilities the supports and services indicated on their IEPs.', 'ESL', 'Not Functionally Accessible', '1', 'Priority to Brooklyn students or residents', 'Then to New York City residents', '250 Hooper Street']
```

---

**How It Works**

1. Initializes a `list`, `new_csv`, containing one empty string element. This will later store our final output.
2. Initializes a `bool`, `inside_quotes`, that will tell our program when we are parsing over a letter inside quotes or outside of quotes.
3. Initializes an `int`, `pos`, that will tell us our position inside of the `new_csv` list.
4. Iterates over each letter in the string.
5. Checks to see if the letter is a `,`:

   - Checks to see if we are parsing over a string inside quotes.

     - If that is `True`, we add that `,` to the string inside of `new_csv`.
     - If that is `False`, we don't add it, we add a new blank string, and we `pos += 1`.
6. If not, checks to see if the letter is a `"`:

   - If `True`, we switch the `bool` `inside_quotes` to True if False or False if true using the handy `not` keyword.
7. If it is any other character, we just add the character to whatever string we are on inside of the list.
8. Do some clean up and remove all blank strings, `''`, from the list.
9. Print it :).

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is specific to a list that exists as an RDD object which is not iterable, so this won't work on it. It's a really weird situation.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with Spark. Is there a way to make it iterable? Also I'm only iterating over a `str` here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem in reading tables. Thankfully, Python has a library that does this for you, so you don't have to do it by hand. You say the csv module won't work, why? Try the following code and comment if it doesn't work!

```
import csv

# please note: KEEP YOUR FILE AS STRINGS when you read in your data.
# Don't do anything to it to try to split it or something.
my_rdd = sc.textFile("/your/file/location/*)
split_with_quotes = my_rdd.map(lambda row: next(csv.reader(row.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True))
```

You should note that the csv parser from the CSV package has a limit of string length of 131,072 characters, so if you have extremely long strings, you'll have to do a bit more work.

To check if this is the case, run the following: `my_rdd.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 131072).count()`. If the `count` is anything other than 0, you have strings that are too long.

Comment: Thanks @Katya... I'm first looking into Spark-specific idiosyncrasies that might prevent importing modules outside of functions. Your solution definitely does work outside of Spark for sure.

Comment: @dstar, I'm confused what you want but I'll let you know that this DOES in fact work within Spark. I've used this exact code multiple times on Spark RDDs. Are you worried about using external packages because you won't have any access to them?